# Is it possible to control the duration and timing function of a NSViewController transition?

Tags: core-animation, transition, nsviewcontroller

I'm using [`NSViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller)'s [`transition(from:to:options:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434407-transition). It is working beautifully, but now I am wanting more control (like a custom [timing function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatimingfunction)).

**Is this possible? Or would it require another approach to transitioning between view controllers?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can modify the animation context if you capture it in an animation group:

```swift
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
    context.duration = 3

    parentController.transition(from: childA, to: childB: options: yourOptions, completionHandler: yourCompletionHandler)
})
```

Unfortunately, it seems, modifying the context's `timingFunction` property doesn't do anything.

---

For OS X 10.11 and older, you may use this shim:
https://gist.github.com/BenLeggiero/63f84d5f7fd8c9b3c9501d1b68110983

Comment: Worthy note that `runAnimationGroup` is only available on OS X 10.12 or newer

Comment: @Newsonic Thank for for noting that! For anyone else wondering, if you must support older versions, use `NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()` and `NSAnimationContext.endGrouping()` to silo the code in my block above, and `NSAnimationContext.current` within that silo to get the current context. [I've written an extension which unlocks the block syntax for the older operating systems](https://gist.github.com/BenLeggiero/63f84d5f7fd8c9b3c9501d1b68110983)